# Custom Picker Renderer is not rendering on first click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am creating a custom picker renderer.
Below is `CustomPickerRenderer.cs`

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPicker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace POC.Droid.CustomRenders
{
    public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        public CustomPickerRenderer()
        {

        }


        private Dialog dialog;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
                return;

            Control.Click += Control_Click1;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Control.Click -= Control_Click1;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void Control_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Picker model = Element;
            dialog = new Dialog(Forms.Context);
            dialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.custom_picker_dialog);
            Android.Widget.ListView listView = (Android.Widget.ListView)dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.lv);
            listView.Adapter = new CustomPickerAdapter(((List<PickerModel>)model.ItemsSource), model.SelectedIndex);
            listView.ItemClick += (object sender1, ItemClickEventArgs e1) =>
            {
                Element.SelectedIndex = e1.Position;
                dialog.Hide();
            };
            if (model.ItemsSource.Count > 3)
            {
                var height = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Height;
                var width = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
                //dialog.Window.SetLayout(700, 800);
                dialog.Window.SetLayout(Convert.ToInt32(width * 2.70), Convert.ToInt32(height * 2));
            }
            dialog.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

My `custom_picker_dialog.axml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Select One Option ?"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"/>
  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/lv"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1">

  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on this picker for the first time

[image]

Then below type of dialog is showing

[image]

Now I close above dialog and click on picker again then below dialog is showing.
and this is right dialog to show.

[image]

I just want to show second dialog all the time. But it's showing after second click.

**UPDATE**

I am using this custom picker in my xaml like this.

```
<custom:CustomPicker x:Name="pickerElement" Title="Select Country" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}" SelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndexChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}"></custom:CustomPicker>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this.

Update `OnElementChanged` method of `CustomPickerRenderer.cs`

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
        return;

    Control.Click += Control_Click;
    Control.FocusChange += Control_FocusChange;
}
```

And create new method

```
private void Control_FocusChange(object sender, FocusChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.HasFocus)
    {
        Control_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```

After doing this issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in xamarin forms 3.4
[Unwanted focus on picker](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4187)

for me i got it solved by using custom renderer for android

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Focusable = false;
                Control.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating the dialog after the first click. You have to create the platform level control inside OnElementChanged. But in this case, it won't help as you trying to display a dialog in picker control. I would suggest using your custom dialog directly without a picker control. Also, You don't need a custom renderer for that.

Have look at this too
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups

Comment: If I wont use custom render for picker than I have to do code for implementing picker's default functionalities like selectedIndex or it's value or it's events. It will be little bit complex. Can you please give an idea about how can I open my custom dialog from first click.

Answer (score 0):

what's your **Xamarin.Forms** version ?

I have the same problem as you when i use the version
`3.4.0.1008975`

then i update the XF to the latest version(`3.6.0.344457`),it works well.

So you could try to update your XF version to the latest;