# Custom Picker Renderer bug - Picker displays twice upon calling Picker.Focus()

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, custom-renderer

I am trying to employ a custom renderer for my Picker controls. I also need my Picker to fire up when I open a tab. I do this by calling the picker's `Focus()` method on tab SelectionChanged.

```cs
if (e.NewPosition == 1)
{
    myPicker.Focus();
}
```

This, however, fires up **two instances** of the picker alert at the same time; one is the *default renderer*, the second one is *my custom renderer*. They are one atop the other, such that when I close the one with *my custom renderer*, the one with *default renderer* is visible.

Simply tapping the Picker will display only one instance, with the custom renderer (this works as intended).

I wrote my custom renderer following [this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70092622/customizing-the-custom-picker-in-xamarin).

I tried the answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68452852/focus-and-unfocus-events-are-triggering-multiple-times-for-datepicker-and-timepi), but the problem is that this skips over the second instance of the picker, which is not what I need. I need to keep the instance that has my custom renderer, not the one with the default renderer.

I also tried to make sure that I am running on the right thread, implementing code described in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784939/trigger-xamarin-forms-picker).

Moreover, I tried to somehow remove events from the CustomRenderer and add them again, like this:

```cs
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Picker> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    Control.Click += null; // hoping this would override all existing events
    Control.Click += Control_Click;
}
```

Finally, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728067/custom-picker-renderer-is-not-rendering-on-first-click) came closest to my situation and I tried following the solutions described in the answers.

None of these worked. I believe that when `Focus()` is called, somehow the default renderer shows up first due to my custom renderer inheriting the default `PickerRenderer`.

How do I enforce the custom renderer?

Or is there a different way for me to fire up my picker upon changing tabs, instead of calling `Focus()`?

My project runs on **Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2545** (latest version as of when I'm writing this question).

### EDIT

I observed the following behaviour: `Control.Click` event is fired AFTER the default renderer is displayed. By debugging the app and placing a break point inside my `Control.Click` handler function, I can see that the app first opens the default picker, and then it halts in said breakpoint.

Comment: Yes, it is the case as you said. And you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLVED

By studying the [`PickerRenderer.cs`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs) class, I realised that there were more functions that had to be overwritten.

To begin with, I made my custom renderer class implement the `IPickerRenderer` interface and added the following function:

```cs
void IPickerRenderer.OnClick()
{
    Control_Click(this, null); // this function handles the Control.Click event
}
```

Moreover, I overwrite the `CallOnClick()` function:

```cs
public override bool CallOnClick()
{
    Control_Click(this, null); // same function, that handles the Control.Click event
    return true;
}
```

Finally, I added this bit of code (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55780689/)) that ensures the Picker shows up only once. Thus, my `OnElementChanged` function looks like this:

```cs
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (Control != null)
    {
        Control.Focusable = false;
    }

    Control.Click += Control_Click; // this is where I link the handler to the event
}
```

The conclusion is that the described behaviour either

- wasn't a bug, which means I just hadn't implemented it correctly
- was a bug, and I managed to find a good workaround

Either way, I managed to solve my problem.

If anyone else stumbles upon this, I hope my work helps.